# What is the best way to aggregate feature importances across different models with identical features?

Tags: python, statistics, bioinformatics, random-forest

I've trained 16 different models on similar biological datasets to predict the occurrence of a specific disease (the target) from ~17000 biological super-pathways (the features). Each dataset has the same features, but not the same model architecture. Additionally, half of the datasets represent the real world disease occurrence (~5%) while the other half are balanced by resampling of the positive class. There are some other data transformations that were done so that each model will emphasize different attributes of the data.

Here's an example of the index of a feature (from a dataframe of ordered feature importances) across all the models and datasets. This specific feature, I am 100% certain, is an important feature in predicting this disease. But you can see how it does vary between models. Each row is the index of a different model.

[image: Feature Index]

As expected different models are picking up different signals and they mostly make biochemical sense despite feature importances varying substantially.

To create one, easy-to-understand product, I've displayed features ordered by their harmonic mean of index across ALL models. Picture is below:

[image: Feature and Harmonic Mean of Index]

What is a better way of showing 1 (or 2) orderings of features from all 16 models?

*feature importance is just sklearn's model.feature_importance_ product (which is the gini importance).

Comment: 16 same models each on slightly different original data? Or 16 actual different models? If the second option than I doubt these scores can be compared. Also 17000 variables is very high dimensional, your results may be very variable, I would try to reduce the dimensionality first. Any old mean is going to work.

Comment: It's a blend of the two. there are 8 slightly different original datasets. on each dataset two model types were trained: gradient boosting and random forest classifiers. 

It was my goal to reduce the variety of features that were chosen without reducing features. I did try to reduce features but about 5% accuracy was lost in those attempts and most of that was in missing disease occurences.

Comment: I would not use such an approach, build all the models that you want, but then choose 1 (the best) and use its final results. Aggregating results from bad (or worse) models is arguably a bad idea. Also, how did you reduce the features? A common approach is to standardize all the variables and remove all the ones with very low variance. Also, your loss in accuracy was it evaluated on a test set / CV or is this the training set accuracy?

Comment: re feature reduction, since we are dealing with taxonomic features, I used a hierarchical feature reduction technique that I wrote myself. I thought it would work, but it seems bacteria have picked up new proteins that their ancestors did not have.
re multiple models: The reason I tried this approach was because I wanted to reduce the amount of variance in the important feature chosen. For example, if 3 features have the same pattern, only 1 will probably be picked. So by manipulating the datasets, I'm able to reduce how many features are 'lost'. What do you think could go wrong here? thanks!

Comment: I don't know, I have never heard of such an approach, I would not do it this way, unless you have some domain knowledge on the subject. Do others in your field do it in such a manner too or something similar? If not I would not complicate things and keep it simple, sometimes less is more.

Comment: It is my first time thinking of something like this as well. And since it is for a paper we are working on we would have to write out a proof for this and simulate other scenarios to show that it works.